# Cut a circular selection into a vector in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I need to create a circular selection of a vector. If I would use Photoshop I would create a circular selection using the marquee tools (M) and then I would crop the image to that selection, invert my selection and remove the non-circular stuff. This is depicted in the gif below. However, how can I achieve the same result in **Illustrator**?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Draw a circle above the shape.
- Select the circle and the shape below it.
- Choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make` from the menu.

[image]

You can learn more about Illustrator clipping masks by reviewing the [**Adobe Illustrator Help Files**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html).

Comment: Thanks! And "Crop" in the pathfinder will remove the remaining "noise".

Comment: Yes, if you wish to work destructively, crop is one way to then trim objects to the clipping mask.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways this could be done.

First draw a circle above the vector, and select both the circle and vector

Then do **one** of the following:

- Open the Pathfinder, and hit "Intersect". This is a boolean operation which will phyiscally cut the graphic where the circle overlaps it, and delete the parts outside the circle.
- Use the ShapeBuilder tool, and click on the head, then hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click on the other pieces to delete them. Essentially the result is a cut shape.
- Do *Object > Clipping Mask > Make*. This makes a clipping path, and is non-destrutive. The original graphic is not cut.
- Ensure the circle is filled white with no stroke, then open the Appearance panel, double click on Opacity, and click *Make Mask*.  This creates an opacity mask, which like a clipping mask is also non-destructive.
- Ensure the circle has no fill and stroke. Select the Shaper Tool, and draw a squiggly line over the parts outside the circle.  This is also creates a non-destructive edit, called a Shaper Group.